# 7zip adding 'DA' instead of 'D' attribute to directories

Tags: batch-file, zip, 7zip

I'm trying to automate a task with a batch-script. Basically it should take a .html-File and a directory and zip them together.

```
7z a -r MyZIP.zip .\My-Folder
7z a MyZIP.zip .\MyFile.htm
```

It also "works". I can unzip it and I get everything back the way I put it in. Now I'm unzipping this on an iOS device and the folder suddenly is a 0 byte file without content. 
I've compared the ZIP created by my script and the one I get when I do it by hand and it looks like the attributes on the folder are set differently.

When I do it by hand (then it works btw.) the folder has the attribute "D" and when my script does it it has the attribute "DA".

Does anyone have an idea why or how I could remove the "A"-attribute?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out it wasn't 7zip that was creating the issue, but the `xcopy` command. When I copied by hand the directory had the correct 'D' attribute.
To make it work I switched from `xcopy` to `copy`